# how to make actions for "_form_fieldset.php" in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm newbie for framework, i'm very confused how to make an action for `_form_fieldset.php` in `symfony 1.4`.
This is my first experience coding with symfony framework. I can create actions for `indexSuccess.php` and other files with `Success.php` for file names. But, I can't create actions for `_form_fieldset.php` on template folders. Anyone know how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those kind of templates you don't create actions: you create **components**.
Those components are inserted on the actions/ folder with the name `components.class.php`.

But, for using those, the template must be called with `include_component(...)` on the parent template file like this:

```
include_component('module_name', 'form_fieldset')
```

If you're using the admin generator, `form_fieldset` is called with `include_partial(...)`. To fix this you have to change the parent template file from `_partial` to `_component` and fix the first parameter.

More information at:
http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_components